# Test CPU utilization in .Net architecture

Tags: .net, jmeter, cpu-usage, load-testing

I am trying to test CPU utilization for a web based CRM application using Jmeter. But as Perfmon (Jmeter plugin) needs JRE to be installed on server (which is not applicable in my case), I am trying to figure out how to do this with any tool other than Jmeter.

I need help on this and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole lot of monitoring tools that can measure and log CPU utilization on a Windows server, the simplest is the built in Performance Monitor utility. You can launch it by typing `perfmon` in the Run dialog box.

Newer versions of windows also have a Resource Monitor which shows pretty graphs of CPU utilization, as does taskmanager, but neither log data to file.

In Performance Monitor, you can add a user defined Data Collector Set, add any performance counters to it, including several CPU counters, and log data to file. You can right-click -> start to start capturing data.

[image]

[Here](http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Using-Windows-7-performance-monitor-to-view-data) is a detailed step-by-step on how to do this. The data is logged as a .blg file as well as a HTML summary report